# Roots of $x^{101}-100x^{100}+100=0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

I do not know how to prove that $x^{101}-100x^{100}+100=0$ has exactly two positive roots.

Some can give me hint for solving this please. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$f'(x)=101x^{100}-100^2x^{99}=x^{99}\left(101x-100^2\right)$$
has two solutions.

$x_{\max}=0, x_{\min}=\frac{100^2}{101}$
Then 
$$x_1<x_{\max}=0<x_2<x_{\min}<x_3$$
Then $x_2,x_2>0$

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** Between any two roots of $f$ there is a root of $f'$

Comment: But the root of $f'$ results in almost the same problem.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla No, it factorises easily.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the polynomial is positive at $0$, negative at (what?) and positive for large $x$, so there area least two positive roots. Now take the derivative. Where is it zero?

Answer (score 1):

You should simply study the variations of the function $f$ defined by $f(x) = x^{101}-100x^{100}+100$ on $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

Descartes' rule of signs indicates that $P(x)=x^{101}-100x^{100}+100$ has either zero or two positive roots.

But $P(0)>0$ and $P(2)<0$ so $P(x)$ has at least one positive root, hence it has exactly two positive roots.